# javascript sort placing middle item at top

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following sort function:

```
var timeArray = new Array('11:41', '11.39', '11:41', '11:41', '11:40', '11:70', '11:39', '11:38', '11:38', '11:37', '11:37');

timeArray.sort(function(c, d) {
        var digit1 = parseInt(c.replace(/\D/g,''));
        var digit2 = parseInt(d.replace(/\D/g,''));
        return  digit1 > digit2;});

var testContent = '';
for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
    testContent += timeArray[i] + '<br />';
}

$('#test').html(testContent);
```

Where I would expect to see the following result:

```
11:37
11:37
11:38
11:38
11.39
11:39
11:40
11:41
11:41
11:41
11:70
```

However, the 11.70 number always appears at the top of the results.  If I change the `11:70` value in the array, no matter what value I use that is the one that will always appear at the start of the results.

Does anyone know how I can sort this properly and why the 11:70 always appears at the top of the list?

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/4Q6Xg/6/)

Comment: sort callback need -/0/+ value to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sort function to

```
timeArray.sort(function(c, d) {
    var digit1 = parseInt(c.replace(/\D/g,''));
    var digit2 = parseInt(d.replace(/\D/g,''));
    return  digit1 - digit2;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q6Xg/9/)

It's expecting a number to be returned, not a boolean.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Ah that explains a lot!  Will accept when it lets me